# iOS 8 swift application, content not centered

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

Everytime I run my iOS application, everything is off-centered. In this screenshot, you can see that the text seems a little off, and the black box is definitely not vertically centered along the page, although the text and box are centered according to the storyboard.

[simulator screenshot](http://s14.postimg.org/rp9v7vv3l/Screen_Shot_2015_02_02_at_6_55_58_PM.png)

[storyboard screenshot](http://s8.postimg.org/jnhhvyyt1/Screen_Shot_2015_02_02_at_7_02_25_PM.png)

I am guessing that the issue must have something to do with the size settings on the bottom of the storyboard. I am using wCompact and hAny.

Any help would be appreciated so that all this will look centered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you don't have your constraints set. You can click on the UIImage or UILabel and go to Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Add Missing Constraints (For All Views) if you want to use Auto Layout. Otherwise, look up some constraint tutorials and you'll have to set them manually. It's not too bad once you get the hang out it!

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! will accept when it lets me